# Rails template conditions

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In PHP I did template consitions with such code:

```
<?php if($item['taste'] > 0):?>taste_plus<?php elseif($item['taste'] == 0):?>taste_zero<?php else:?>taste_minus<?php endif;?>
```

And I did number formatting with `<?php echo number_format($item['taste'], 2)?>` for fetch them to "2.00" format.

How to do things like that in Rails templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct translation of your template code would look something like this:

```
<% if @item.taste > 0 %>taste_plus<% elsif @item.taste == 0 %>taste_zero<% else %>taste_minus<% end %>
```

In this example, I've made the code more object-oriented and used the @item member variable, which is more Ruby/Rails-like, rather than use a PHP array to transfer variables to the HTML template.

However, rather than use this direct translation, a Rails developer would more likely try to reduce the need to have so much logic in the template by making a helper function like this:

```
def taste_helper(taste)
  if taste > 0
    taste_plus
  elsif taste == 0
    taste_zero
  else
    taste_minus
  end 
end
```

... So that she could put this in her template:

```
<%= taste_helper(@item.taste) %>
```

For formatting numbers in your template you could use the Rails number_with_precision function like this:

```
number_with_precision(2, :precision => 2)
```

The above formatting function would output '2.00'. The docs for [number_with_precision() are here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision).

Comment: Thanks! To which file should i add `def taste_helper(taste)`?

Comment: Put your helper method into app/helpers/application_helper.rb to make it globally available in all templates. You can also put it in file that is only loaded for a specific controller view, for example if you had a HomeController, you could put the method in app/helpers/home_helper.rb. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You can see some more examples here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActionView/Custom_Helpers