# Rails partial rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to render partial depending on current controller?
For example we have got this partial:
`<h2>Funny <em>title</em></h2>` 
And depending on controller i'd like to change `<em>` into `<strong>`
We can do this by passing locals to partial and use conditional:
`<% if :controller == "something" tag="em" elsif :controller == "other" tag="strong" %>

<h2>Funny <<%= tag %>>title</<%= tag %>></h2>`
But what if there are n controllers? That number of conditions in view doesn't look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just set an instance variable in a before_filter and then grab it in the partial.

For instance, in your controller:

```
class FooController ...
  before_filter set_subtitle_flag

  ...

  private

  def set_subtitle_flag
    @subtitle_strong = true
  end
end
```

Then in your partial:

```
<% if @subtitle_strong %>
  <strong>Foo bar baz</strong>
<% else %>
  <em>Foo bar baz</em>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is the best option. Checking the controller in the view is breaking MVC. What if you rename the controller? What if you want to use this view from another controller? Both of those would cause your logic to fail, but an instance variable won't.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to not use server-side logic, but to use CSS.

Instead of:

```
<h2>Funny <em>title</em></h2>
```

You could wrap your title in a span tag and style that with a dynamic CSS class name based upon your controller name:

```
<h2>Funny <span class="<%= title_class %>">title</span></h2>
```

Pass the controller name to the partial as a local variable called '`title_class`' and have CSS selector variations to match these names in your stylesheet.

Comment: It was only(bad) example, in real there will be some versions of whole <h2> tag.

Comment: Ah. In that case the "Rails Way" would be to put your switching logic into a helper function. I answered a question with a helper function example recently. You can read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130001/rails-template-conditions/5130177#5130177